# Linux BBS software from the year 1992

Tags: identify-this-software, linux, bbs

What was the right name of a software platform for some Linux BBSs in the year 1992? "Galactico" if I remember well...

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of [Galacticomm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galacticomm)? But it wasn't based on Linux.

Comment: 1992 seems awful early, even SLS only appeard in August 1992.